# How to update mysql timestamp if a string in the same row has been updated?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, sql-update

There are 3 columns -> `'Name', 'Created', 'Last_Modified'`.

I would Last Modified to show the date if and only if the name has been modified.
Each time the name is updated, Last Modified must be updated.

How can this be achieved?

```
CREATE TABLE t (
   Name VARCHAR(255)
 , Created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 , Last_Modified DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
```

Comment: You can simply `ALTER` the column `Last Modified` to have a `ON UPDATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE` ? Then every `UPDATE` that changes a value should also update the `Last Modified`  column.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Yes, can you give the code snippet as I am getting an error?

Comment: Oh did i say `CURRENT_DATE` i meant `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ` see mine answer, i always mix those up.. Mine opinion MySQL should also allow `CURRENT_DATE` or `CURRENT_DATETIME` on `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` datatypes but for `DATETIME` for sure.. Because it makes more sense writting `column_name DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_DATETIME` in mine opinion instead off `column_name  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this MySQL code should work.

```
ALTER TABLE t
CHANGE last_modified last_modified DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gJXdqNtsMsXNHeXYaq6dx4/0)